# Spring IllegalStateExceptions when upgrading to Java 8

Tags: java, spring, tomcat6

Quite new to this but I'm trying to upgrade to java 8 from java 6.

I built using java 8. It compiled fine but got some server errors when I ran the application. I read that java 8 required spring to be upgraded to version 4 so I followed [this](http://xpadro.blogspot.ie/2014/01/migrating-spring-mvc-restful-web.html) guide to do such. After a bit of heartache everything is back compiling but I am still getting errors. I know it is still a versioning issue but I'm not sure where to start with trying to figure out where...

I am running tomcat 6.0.33, java 8 (hopefully), spring 4(also hopefully) and it is a RESTful web service.

I have updated tomcat to run java 8 and my path variables are up to date.

Merci buckets! Here's the full trace.

```
2015-01-07 14:53:54.270 ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:70)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:253)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Jan 07, 2015 2:53:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 07, 2015 2:53:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2015-01-07 14:53:54.345 INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Jan 07 14:53:45 GMT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-01-07 14:53:54.354 WARN : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Jan 07 14:53:45 GMT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1049)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:558)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.__stop(StandardContext.java:4886)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
2015-01-07 14:53:54.357 WARN : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Jan 07 14:53:45 GMT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:558)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.__stop(StandardContext.java:4886)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Edit:
So I tried to remove asm from my project as such

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->
```

But I am still getting the

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)...
```

I am also now using tomcat 8

I looked through all of the children poms and added exclusions to anything that was referencing asm. 
I have no idea why this is being called...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit 2:
After running mvn dependency:tree here are the asm related parts of the output (the output itself was massive so I don't want to post it all)

```
[INFO] com.gustavo:maven-j2as-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:jar:0.0.0.M2a:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:jar:0.0.0.M2a:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile

[INFO] com.gustavo:maven-j2as-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:jar:0.0.0.M2a:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:jar:0.0.0.M2a:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile

[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile

[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile

[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile

[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile

[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile

[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile

[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3:compile

[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3:compile

[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile

[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
```

I have 30 modules so I guess 12 of them still have a dependency on asm :/

Comment: How are you putting this project together -- maven or something else? It looks like you may have an older version of [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), a bytecode manipulation library that Spring apparently uses. Only pretty new versions of ASM support Java 8.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If you scroll down a bit, the IllegalStateException is there. My guess is that it's caused by the bad class load that the first exception indicates.

Comment: @yshavit Missed that. I'd also guess they are a result of that initial IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Yup, it's maven. Gonna try it on a newer version of tomcat then check back in. I'll also have a look at asm. Thanks guys

Comment: So I am trying to remove asm from the project as it doesn't play nice with Java 8. In my root pom I have removed asm and added an exclusion to it in spring-core but it is still giving me an illegal argument exception on org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.

Comment: Post the output of `mvn dependency:tree` . As of Spring 4 there is no more `spring-asm` so if that still is in yuor project it is being pulled in from something else.

Comment: Okay the output is huge. Will try to pull out the relevant parts and edit my post. Thanks

Comment: Please post the exact Spring version you are using. Also post the result of `java -version`.

Comment: java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Spring - 4.1.4.RELEASE

Comment: I can't see that happening. The `ClassReader` constructor in that version of Spring (assuming all your Spring libraries are on the same version) has the piece of code that throws an `IllegalArgumentException` commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an older version of webflow which had a transitive dependency on an older version of Spring

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 6 does not support Java 8, you might want to start by upgrading your tomcat version to 9 something : 
http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: 8 seems to be the newest version of tomcat. I actually did try it on there before the spring update but was still getting the same error so thought it was unrelated. Will let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, so your issue probably boils down to spring related dependencies upgrades. Take a look around : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238505/java-lang-illegalstate-exception-lifecylceprocessor-and-applicationeventmulticas